# Pull down menus on mobile incorrectly sized

Tags: bug

This started occurring only in the last week or so. Only affects portrait layout, but it makes the menus completely unusable:

[image: dropdown menu too narrow]

Comment: Ah, good find on the duplicate. I was mobile at the DMV and didn't see anything that looked related (or recent). The reference to the reputation dropdown *specifically* rather than *all three* probably made it harder to find.